# How to do equal comparison in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

I am just wondering in C or C++, for the expression:

```
b == c || b == d
```

Can I do something like:

```
b == (c || d)
```

and get the same behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first expression 
`b == c || b == d` will give you true if `b` is equal to either `c` or `d`.

The second expression 
`b == (c || d)` will check only if `b` is either equal to 0 or 1 because the output of `c || d` is binary.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int b=10,c=9,d=10;
    cout << (b ==c || b ==d )<<endl;
    cout<< ( b == ( c || d)) <<endl;
    d=11;
    cout << (b ==c || b ==d )<<endl;
    cout<< ( b == ( c || d)) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1
0
0
0
```

Now you can clearly see that both expressions are not same.

Comment: `b` doesn't have to be `1` in order to be `true`.

Comment: for the second case, if c and d are both 0 then b have to be 0 in order to be true; else b have to be one in order to be true

Comment: Strictly speaking, `(c || d)` is *boolean*, and in the `b == (c || d)` comparison, it is promoted to `int` and becomes `1`.

Comment: @jogojapan: `printf("%d", 2 == (1 || 1));` prints “0” in both C and C++. I tested. As you note `(c || d)` is promoted to `int` and, if true, becomes 1, at which point `b` must be one in order for the `==` to produce true.

Comment: A convincing third demonstration would be to set `b = 1`.

Comment: @jogojapan: In C, `(c || d)` is of type `int`, with the value `0` or `1`. C does have a built-in Boolean type called `_Bool`, added by the 1999 standard, but it's not used for any of the built-in operators that yield logically boolean values; they all yield `int`. In C++, the result is of type `bool`. (I see the question is now tagged both C and C++.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I was talking about C++ because this answer is C++.

Comment: @KeithThompson: the question was dual-tagged when asked; the content originally asked about C, so  I briefly removed the C++ tag, but since the best answer was in C++ and matched the tags, I ended up adding C++ to the question text (and reinstating the tag) — after about 5 minutes.  The answer is near enough the same in C and C++ — the difference is the `bool` vs `int` part, but the numeric values end up the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, operators in C and C++ don't implicitly distribute over subexpressions like that. Evaluation is defined strictly in terms of the direct association of operators with operands. There are no "shortcuts" as you might have in mathematics or English.

If you write code that incorrectly assume such implicit distribution, you're likely to end up with an expression that's syntactically and semantically valid, but that doesn't do what you expect.

The `||` operator yields a value of `1` or `true` if either operand is true (non-zero) or a value of `0` or `false` if both operands are false (equal to zero). And the operands needn't be boolean; they can be of any scalar type. (In C the result is of type `int`; in C++ it's of type `bool`.) The expression

```
b == c || b == d
```

is equivalent to

```
(b == c) || (b == d)
```

and yields a true result if `b` is equal to `c` *or* if `b` is equal to `d`. But this expression:

```
b == (c || d)
```

computes the value of `(c || d)`, and the tests whether `b` is equal to the result of that subexpression.

A similar possible source of confusion is that

```
x < y < z
```

is not equivalent to

```
(x < y) && (y < z)
```

Rather, it's equivalent to

```
(x < y) < z
```

where the `false` or `true` (in C++) or `0` or `1` (in C) result of `x < y` is compared to the value of `z`.